# php whith json does not word?

Tags: php, json, angular

I had to conceive a site with angular in front and php in backend which manages a crud in an admin space. I had to do an api rest to get php to return the data from the database to angular in json. The problem is that locally everything is fine but not when I deploy it on a web server.

I get this kind of error message in the logs.

```
[15-Jun-2020 23:24:45 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  require_once(dashboard/models/model.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/keviqffq/public_html/admin/api.php on line 8
[15-Jun-2020 23:24:45 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:
[15-Jun-2020 23:24:45 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() /home/keviqffq/public_html/admin/api.php:0
[15-Jun-2020 23:24:45 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:
```

Comment: What code throws that error? show that code too

Comment: Looks like it can't find a necessary file... Are you sure everything is uploaded, on the right place, and especially all your relative paths are set right?